# How do I prevent by Rx test from hanging?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I am reproducing my Rx issue with a simplified test case below. The test below hangs. I am sure it is a small, but fundamental, thing that I am missing, but can't put my finger on it.

```cs
   public class Service
   {
        private ISubject<double> _subject = new Subject<double>();
        public void Reset()
        {
            _subject.OnNext(0.0);
        }

        public IObservable<double> GetProgress()
        {
            return _subject;
        }
    }

    public class ObTest
    {
        [Fact]
        private async Task SimpleTest()
        {
            var service = new Service();

            var result = service.GetProgress().Take(1);

            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                service.Reset();
            });

            await result;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

My attempt above was to simplify the problem a little and understand it. In my case `GetProgress()` is a merge of various `Observables` that publish the download progress, one of these `Observables` is a `Subject<double>` that publishes `0` everytime somebody calls a method to delete the download.

The race condition identified by *Enigmativity* and *Theodor Zoulias* may(??) happen in real life. I display a view which attempts to get the progress, however, quick fingers delete it just in time.

What I need to understand a bit more is if the download is started again (subscription has taken place by now, by virtue of displaying a view, which has already made the subscription) and somebody again deletes it.

```cs
   public class Service
   {
        private ISubject<double> _deleteSubject = new Subject<double>();
        public void Reset()
        {
            _deleteSubject.OnNext(0.0);
        }

        public IObservable<double> GetProgress()
        {
            return _deleteSubject.Merge(downloadProgress);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens to the view when a `0` is received? Does it become hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't hanging. It's awaiting an observable that sometimes never gets a value.

You have a race condition.

The `Task.Run` is sometimes executing to completion before the `await result` creates the subscription to the observable - so it never sees the value.

Try this code instead:

```
private async Task SimpleTest()
{
    var service = new Service();

    var result = service.GetProgress().Take(1);

    var awaiter = result.GetAwaiter();

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        service.Reset();
    });

    await awaiter;
}
```

Comment: @resp78 - What are you trying to test with this code?

Answer (score 1):

The line `await result` creates a subscription to the observable. The problem is that the notification `_subject.OnNext(0.0)` may occur before this subscription, in which case the value will pass unobserved, and the `await result` will continue waiting for a notification for ever. In this particular example the notification is always missed, at least in my PC, because the subscription is delayed for around 30 msec (measured with a `Stopwatch`), which is longer than the time needed for the task that resets the service to complete, probably because the JITer must load and compile some RX-related assembly. The situation changes when I do a warm-up by calling `new Subject<int>().FirstAsync().Subscribe()` before running the example. In that case the notification is observed almost always, and the hanging is avoided.

I can think of two robust solutions to this problem.

1. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59188384/11178549) suggested by Enigmativity, to create an awaitable subscription before starting the task that resets the service. This can be done with either `GetAwaiter` or `ToTask`.
2. To use a [`ReplaySubject<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211810(v%3Dvs.103)) instead of a plain vanilla `Subject<T>`.

> Represents an object that is both an observable sequence as well as an observer. Each notification is broadcasted to all subscribed and future observers, subject to buffer trimming policies.

The `ReplaySubject` will cache the value so that it can be observed by the future subscription, eliminating the race condition. You could initialize it with a `bufferSize` of 1 to minimize the memory footprint of the buffer.

Comment: "Subjects are hot" - No, not necessarily. `ReplaySubject` is both hot and cold.

Comment: "the Take operator in this case, the resulting observable is cold." - No, it's not. If the source is hot then applying `.Take(1)` doesn't change the hotness.

Comment: There is no "warm-up" time. What you're describing is just a race condition.

Comment: I do agree with your two solutions though. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right, my first paragraph was bs from start to finish. I updated my answer.